# how to increment variable vlaue as json payload in python

Tags: python, json

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost:8181")

device_id = 1

while device_id < 1000:

    payload = "\n{\n  \"deviceId\": \"device_id\",\n  \"osVendor\": \"abcd\"\n}"

    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'postman-token': "03ac94dc-d208-95dd-7bf2-2e6c1f194316"
        }

    conn.request("POST", "/PNBQC/v1/registerbox", payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

- I need to increment the device_id until 1000 but its executing the string as it is instead of value.
  kindly provide the solution.
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the payload as a dictionary that you then dump into a string after manipulation.

```
import json

device_id = 1

while device_id < 1000:
    payload = {"deviceId": device_id, "osVendor": "abcd"}
    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    device_id += 1
```